# Issue with Powershell and date functions

Tags: powershell, datetime, powershell-4.0

I have a script which pulls information from our SQL server estate.  The scripts pulls off some dates (last check DBCC) and does some calculations for aging.

The problematic section of the code is here:

```
$lastDBCC_CHECKDB=$database.ExecuteWithResults("DBCC DBINFO () WITH TABLERESULTS").Tables[0] | Where-Object {$_.Field -eq "dbi_dbccLastKnownGood"} | Select-object Value
            $lastDBCC_CHECKDB=$lastDBCC_CHECKDB.value -f (get-date)  
            $lastDBCC_CHECKDB=$lastDBCC_CHECKDB.Substring(0,19) | get-date -format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
            Add-Member -InputObject $dbinfo -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Last CheckDBCC' -Value $lastDBCC_CHECKDB
            $DBCCProblem = "None"
            if ($lastDBCC_CHECKDB -lt $date.AddDays(-7))                                             { $DBCCProblem = "No CheckDBCC in the last week" }
            if ($lastDBCC_CHECKDB -eq "01/01/1900 00:01:00")                                         { $DBCCProblem = "CheckDBCC has never run" }
            Add-Member -InputObject $dbinfo -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'DBCC Issues'                -Value $DBCCProblem
```

My date calculations are working, however, it looks like the process is calculating based on the current `$date` being in a different format.

No matter what I try, I can't seem to force `$date` to the correct format without the `AddDays` function failing.

On my Powershell terminal, if run `$date` (set in the script from the `get-date` cmdlet), I get:

```
09 July 2015 15:42:26
```

However, if I run:

```
$date=get-date
```

I get the incorrect format of:

```
09/07/2015 15:42:26
```

Notice the date and month (American format).  My calculations are being done against that date despite me specifying the date format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:ss".

Again, if I set `$date` in the script as:

```
$date=Get-date
```

My `AddDays` calculation function fails with:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'AddDays'.
At ...\SQLServerBackupSummary.ps1:122 char:21
+                 if ($lastDBCC_CHECKDB -lt $now.AddDays(-7))                      ...
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Specifying the addition of Datetime doesn't work:

```
 $lastDBCC_CHECKDB.Datetime -lt $date.AddDays(-7))
```

That seems to just mess everything up.

Any pointers for this gratefully appreciated, I'm still fairly new to Powershell but have never struggled with date conversion in other scripting languages before.

Comment: Try [`[DateTime]::ParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with format against DBCC date strings. Note, `/` and `:` are substitutes for locale-specific date and time delimiters, so they should be escaped in the format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has nothing to do with date formats. Based on the line :

```
if ($lastDBCC_CHECKDB -eq "01/01/1900 00:01:00")
```

I guess $lastDBCC_CHECKDB is a string and therefore you are comparing 2 strings. You want to compare 2 dates: so either try

```
if ([DateTime]$lastDBCC_CHECKDB -lt $date.AddDays(-7))
```

or follow [this link](http://dusan.kuzmanovic.net/2012/05/07/powershell-parsing-date-and-time/) if you need to parse custom date formats or more info.

Comment: The addition of the DateTime function before the variable rather than after (where I had tried it) works - thanks for this.

Comment: Hi @Huskie69, it's not a function, it's a type cast. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/2007.03.powershell.aspx